# className is missing for styled component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, styled-components

I have defined such "Logo" component:

```
const Logo = ({ className }: { className: string }) => (
  <Link to="/" className={className}>
    <img src={logo} alt="logo" />
  </Link>
);
```

Which has the open possibility to be styled with passing down className.

But when I'm using it with the typescript like that:

```
const StyledLogo = styled(Logo)`
  margin-left: 4.5rem;
`;
```

... somewhere in render:

```
<StyledLogo />
```

Then I've got such error:

> Error:(33, 6) TS2741: Property 'className' is missing in type '{}' but
>   required in type 'Pick &
>   Partial>, "className">'.

How to let know typescript that all my styled components will pass down this className property and it will be always there?

Answer (score 1):

It should be possible to resolve this issue by marking the `className` parameter of `Logo` [as optional](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/functions.html#optional-and-default-parameters) by doing the following:

```
/* Add ? after className */
const Logo = ({ className }: { className?: string }) => (
  <Link to="/" className={className}>
    <img src={logo} alt="logo" />
  </Link>
);

const StyledLogo = styled(Logo)`
  margin-left: 4.5rem;
`;

/* No ts error reported now */
<StyledLogo />
```

Hope that helps!

---

#### Update

Alternatively, to avoid the optional `className` method above you can take this approach:

```
/* Define type to minimise verbosity */
type LogoProps = { className: string };

/* Define strongly typed Logo function with defined type */
const Logo = (props: LogoProps) => (
  <Link to="/" className={props.className}>
    <img src={"logo"} alt="logo" />
  </Link>
);

/* TS explicitly aware of prop set being passed to Logo via type */
export const StyledLogo = styled((props: LogoProps) => <Logo {...props} />)`
  margin-left: 4.5rem;
`;

 /* Usage */
 <StyledLogo />
```

This method ensures that TS is aware of the actual prop set being passed to the `Logo` component.

Comment: Ah, this help. Thank you but that solution doesn't change fact that typescript is not aware of the styled(Logo) implicitly passes className prop.

Comment: @PatrykJanik sorry for the delay coming back to you - just updated the answer, hope I interpreted your feedback correctly :)

Comment: Thank you for another response. But this solution isn't generic. It means I would need to "wrapp" every styled() component just to tell typescript something I always know :/